# State object not updating with response data in function call

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently attempting to set a state called 'newTask', which is an object in the following format:

```
const [newTask, setNewTask] = useState({ _id: "", parentTaskId: "", accountId: "", title: "", status: false, createdDate: "" })
```

The state is being set based upon the success of a backend post request, and receiving response data back.

The response data is correct. It definitely returns the correct values, namely id, parentTaskId, accountId, title, status and createdDate.

As an example, here's a response returned:

```
_id: "example id"
accountId: "example"
createdDate: "2021-05-18T08:59:18.468Z"
parentTaskId: "example"
status: false
title: "example title"
```

However, when I go to set the state with this response, it's not correctly inputting the data, they're all just empty strings when they're appended to a parent state array.

Here's my code:

```
const addTask = () => {

    axios.post("/apiquery", {
        parentTaskId: id,
        accountId: userId,
        title: title,
        status: false,
        createdDate: new Date()
    })
    .then(async (response) => {
        const data = await response.data.response
        return data
    })
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
        return setNewTask({ _id: data._id, parentTaskId: data.parentTaskId, accountId: data.accountId, title: data.title, status: false, createdDate: data.createdDate })
    })
    .then(() => {
        setTasks([...tasks, newTask])
        console.log(tasks)
    })
    
}
```

Hopefully here you can there's the following steps:

- The request is posted to my API
- I await the response.data
- I console log the data, and then attempt to set my newTask state
- I then attempt to append this newTask onto the end of my overall tasks array state

The console log data is correct. The console log tasks shows that the data appended is just an object of empty strings, indicating that it's not appending the correct newTask (seems to be the initial one) or the newTask isn't being appended correctly.

Any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong would be really appreciated.

Comment: don't mix `async-await` syntax with promise chaining and where is the `newTask` coming from in the last `then()` method?

Comment: Try the following steps: 1. Remove the `async` keyword from the callback function of the first `then` method. 2. Instead of awaiting, return the result of `response.data.response`. 3.  In the 2nd `then` method, create a `newTask` object from the `data` parameter. 4. Pass this `newState` object to `setTasks` and `setnewTask` functions. 5. Remove the last `then` method.

Comment: Yep that's worked. It's made me realise I don't necessarily need that newTask state either - I can just have a state string which I pass to the post request as a parameter. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the code with the following and try.

```
const addTask = () => {

    axios.post("/apiquery", {
        parentTaskId: id,
        accountId: userId,
        title: title,
        status: false,
        createdDate: new Date()
    })
    .then((response) => response.data.response)
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        const task = {
            ...data,
            status: false
        }
        setNewTask(task);
        setNewTask([...tasks, task]);
    })
}
```

No need to use additional then block for adding the current task to the array.